# Reading data back into a binary search tree

Tags: java, serialization, binary-search-tree

I have a program that adds a node containing `(int studentNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String major, double gpa)` and to "save" it to a file, I have this method:

```
public void saveRecord (Node focusNode) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"saving file...");
    try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));         

        if (focusNode != null){

            System.out.println(focusNode);
            output.writeObject((focusNode));

            preOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);

            preOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
        }//end if
        output.close();

    }
   //catch exceptions
}//end save
```

Now, I want to pull back each node that was written and be able to sort them differently, (such as by major, gpa, etc). How do I go about doing that while retaining all of the fields so that they are searchable when I read them back in? I have thought about reading them back into a list, but it adds each line in with none of the previously mentioned parameters. My `addNode` method adds each node to the tree using those parameters so I can't just call that. How would I do this?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Reading line by line in a serialized file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050079/reading-line-by-line-in-a-serialized-file)l Don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: @EJP it's actually not the same thing, the other one was more expanded. Also, this one was never even commented on let alone answered

Comment: It is the same question with the same answer. Your acceptance proves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included the answer to this question in my answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050079/reading-line-by-line-in-a-serialized-file/23051884#23051884).