# Reading line by line in a serialized file

Tags: java, serialization

I have a serialized file and I'm trying to grab each line in it and add that into a LinkedList. Can I do this using the `Scanner` or since its serialized do I have to you `ObjectInputStream`? I assume with the scanner you could use scanner.nextLine() or something similar but I don't think the OOS has something like that? How would I go about adding each line to a seperate node in the list?

This question is also tied to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049545/reading-data-back-into-a-binary-search-tree). This is how the tree is originally serialized.

Comment: A serialized file is binary data, it is not text and there is no notion of a line. You have this problem to solve first... Why don't you just serialize an array of your objects instead?

Comment: Well it's kind of complicated what I'm trying to do. I am working with binary search trees, and serialize the tree to a file, then want to read those nodes and the tree back into another tree when the program is restarted...@fge

Comment: How do you serialize the original tree to a file?

Comment: @wiz3kid look at the link I just added to the question, that will show how I write it.

Comment: Because you serialize it using `ObjectOutputStream` you *must* use `ObjectInputStream` to deserialize it.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I had figured. But how do I go about reading it object by object? like how can I create some method that will loop through and grab each object from that until there is nothing left?

Comment: There are no lines in a serialized file. There are objects.  Reading it object by object just requires a *loop.* You do know what a loop is? NB The loop must terminate when you catch EOFException. But if you serialized a tree, it should only be necessary to read *one* object: the tree. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP apparently you didn't read my comment right above yours. I know that I need to loop through it. What I'm saying is that I don't know _how_ to loop through it and grab each object. And I'm not serializing the whole tree at once, I'm doing it node by node. so I do have to read it object by object, not just one.

Comment: You know what a loop is but you don't know how to loop? Seriously? Never heard of 'while()'? Or 'for ()'? In any case you don't need a loop. You've serialized one object: the tree, so you deserialize one object: the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no new lines in a serialized file (unless you somehow make it that way when you originally write it). You will have to use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` to serialize and deserialize. If you are serializing a bunch of objects your best option would probably be to serialize the *entire* list, and then deserialize the whole thing at once again, and add it back to a new list.  Judging by your other question, a good option might be to add each node into a list rather than writing each object to file separately:

```
... 
if (focusNode != null){

        System.out.println(focusNode);
       list.add(focusNode);

        preOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);

        preOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
    }//end if
...
```

and then to save it:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(file))) {

        output.writeObject(lList);//this will write the list as a whole to the file
}
```

and to read it back, I would suggest putting it back into the list:

```
try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(file))) {
        newList = (List) input.readObject();
```

from there, if you need to use the objects again, you can pull them out of the list, etc.

Comment: It's kind of a workaround to what I was looking to do, but it works! Thank you!

Comment: If you take the time to write each object to file as you had done before, it's going to take a lot longer (especially if there are many objects) to iterate through and do it individually as opposed to writing the whole list at once. Glad that it works :)

Comment: @user3524177 It's not 'kind of a workaround'. It's the correct answer. What you were trying to do was the workaround.